# Min-Width Table

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table, width

I am attempting to create a min-width table of 500px with a cell containing a textarea with a min-width of 300px. The table's min-width doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm using CSS to style the table and the textarea. Is this a known issue? I've posted the code below.

Must appear correctly in IE7

ASPX Page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="./CSS/SpecialOps.css" />
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="./CSS/myadditions.css" />
        <title>PFS Special OPS - My Additions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- #include file="./SSI/header.aspx -->
        <div id="spacer">
            <div id="logospacer">

            </div>
            <div class="tabspacer">

            </div>
            <div class="tabspacer highlightspacer">

            </div>
            <div class="tabspacer">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="contentinner">
                <div class="divtitle">
                    Add News Excerpt
                </div>
                <div id="addnews">
                    <table id="addnewstbl">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Title:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="addnewsform"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Excerpt:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="addnewsform"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Your Name:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Steven Norris
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
/*
* Stylesheet for my additions page of Special OPS
* Created by Steven T. Norris on 4/4/2012
* Last Update:          Update By:
*/
#addnews
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
    padding:3px;
}
#addnews
{

}
#addnewstbl
{
    min-width:500px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
}
.addnewsform
{
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want. the given code is working. whats the issue?

Comment: @DineshSwami The given code is not working. The table is not extending it's width to fit the input elements. The input elements get to 300px, but the table remains too small and cuts off the overflow. I'm using IE7. Perhaps your browser interprets the CSS differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that achieves the desired effect. Not particularly the same method, but the same end-product at least. There's some extra bits in the code you don't need to worry about, but essentially set your container at 100% and your form elements at some fractionaly percentage of that 100 and the affect should be achieved. I used 98% in this case, just to give a little buffer on the right edge. It isn't ideal, but it works, and the bugs with this method are all-but-unnoticable.

ASPX Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="./CSS/SpecialOps.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="./CSS/myadditions.css" />
    <title>PFS Special OPS - My Additions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- #include file="./SSI/header.aspx -->
    <div id="spacer">
        <div id="logospacer">

        </div>
        <div class="tabspacer">

        </div>
        <div class="tabspacer highlightspacer">

        </div>
        <div class="tabspacer">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentinner">
            <div class="divtitle">
                Add News Excerpt
            </div>
            <div id="addnews">
                <table id="addnewstbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="addnewstitlecell">
                            Title:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="addnewsform"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="addnewstitlecell">
                            Excerpt:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea rows="10" class="addnewsform"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="addnestitlecell">
                            Catagory:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
                                <option value="AVP/VP">AVP/VP</option>
                                <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
                                <option value="Correspondence">Correspondence</option>
                                <option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
                                <option value="ERAC">ERAC</option>
                                <option value="Government Payer">Government Payer</option>
                                <option value="PFS">PFS</option>
                                <option value="Regulatory">Regulatory</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="addnewstitlecell">
                            Submitted By:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Steven Norris
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="divtitle">
                Previously Added
            </div>
            <div id="prevadded">
                <div class="prevaddedtop">
                    <div class="prevaddedtitle">
                        News Excerpt Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddedcontent">
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddeduser">
                        -Steven Norris
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddedbuttons">
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prevaddedtop">
                    <div class="prevaddedtitle">
                        News Excerpt Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddedcontent">
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddeduser">
                        -Steven Norris
                    </div>
                    <div class="prevaddedbuttons">
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/**
* Overall stylesheet for PFS Special OPS
* Created By Steven T. Norris on 4/3/2012
* Last Updated:         Last Updated By:
*/

/*
* Overall Navigation
* #navigation min-width mirrors .tab widths + #logoimg width + 200px allowance for #welcome width
* #navigation height mirrors #logoimg height
*/
#navigation
{
    min-width:677px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-color:Black;
    height:100px;
}

/* 
* TopTabs
* .tab height and width mirrors image height and width for ./Images/blueTab.png
* .tabspacer width, margin-right, and padding mirrors .tab
* .tabspacer bottom mirrored in #content
* .tab top mirrors #logoimg height - .tab height - .tab padding-top - .tab padding-bottom
*/
.tab
{
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:76px;
    left:20px;
    font-size:large;
    background-image:url('../Images/blueTab.png');
    text-align:center;
}
.tablink
{
    color:Black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tablink:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
}
.tabspacer
{
    height:2px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding:2px;
    left:20px;
    bottom:2px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:#0383de;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:black;
}

/*
* Logo
* #logospacer width mirrors #logoimg width
*/
#logo
{
    float:left;
}
#logoimg
{
    width:130px;
    height:100px;
}
#logospacer
{
    width:130px;
    height:1px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}

/*
* Content
* #content min-width mirrors #navigation
* #content background-color mirrors ./Images/blueTab.png bottom color
*/
#content
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#0386e1;
    position:relative;
    bottom:2px;
    min-width:677px;
}
#contentinner
{
    margin:10px;
    background-color:White;
    overflow:auto;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
    padding:5px;
}

/*
* Welcome
* #welcome height, padding, and top mirrors .tab
*/

#welcome
{
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    padding:2px;
    top:76px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/*
* Spacers
* #spacer min-width mirrors #navigation
* #highlightspacer background-color mirrors ./Images/blueTab.png bottom color
*/
#spacer
{
    min-width:677px;
}
.highlightspacer
{
    background-color:#0383de;
    border-bottom-color:#0383de;
    z-index:1;
}

    /*
    * Titles placed directly above a bordered div
    */
    .divtitle
    {
        position:relative;
        top:4px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    /*
    * Buttons
    */
    .button
    {
        background:url('../Images/blueButton.png');
        border-style:none;
        width:100px;
        height:20px;
    }
    .button:hover
    {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
/*
* Stylesheet for my additions page of Special OPS
* Created by Steven T. Norris on 4/4/2012
* Last Update:          Update By:
*/
#addnews
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
    padding:3px;
}
#addnewstbl
{
    width:100%;
}
.addnewsform
{
    width:98%;
}
.addnewstitlecell
{
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#prevadded
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
    padding:3px;
}
.prevaddeduser
{
    text-align:right;
}
.prevaddedbuttons
{
    text-align:right;
}
.prevaddedtitle
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.prevaddedtop
{
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:Black;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i would do.  Add the following to th

```
#addnewstbl
{
    width: 100%
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
}

#addnews
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:Black;
    padding:3px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: This makes resizing smaller fine, but two things happen. The table becomes elongated past what it should if the window is larger than 500px. Also, the textarea remains unchanged, whereas it should grow/shrink as the window grows/shrinks

Comment: you may need to set the textarea width to 100% also so it expands as the div expands also.  i'm not sure what you mean by tables elongated past the window if it is larger than 500px?

Comment: I'm referring to the browser window. Say the browser window is larger than 500px, the table stretches out, making each column an even amount of space apart, which means the textarea is now spaced pretty far away from the label, giving a elongated look to the whole thing. I know a work around, but if feels messy to me. Once I can post answers I'll post my work around. Maybe that's the best route anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width#compatibilitysection), min-width is buggy in IE7.  I recommend a different approach that doesn't use it.

Comment: Yeah I think it works fine for divs, but for tables it seems to be unworkable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Comparability view issue in Internet Explorer.

If you hunt around the net there are a few different ways to work around this, but in short, you need to disable this mode in IE for min-width to work.